# How to apply 'OR' condition in redis keys command

Tags: regex, redis

E.g.

```
keys X 'or' Y
```

should print

```
1)X
2)Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis does OR only as a Bit operation.

For Example:

```
redis>  SET key1 "foobar"

OK

redis>  SET key2 "abcdef"

OK

redis>  BITOP AND dest key1 key2

(integer) 6

redis>  GET dest

"`bc`ab"
```

You can know more about this on http://redis.io/commands/bitop

Comment: can you elobarate on your use case?

Comment: just like in regex [X|Y] gives X and Y. what should i use with keys command to get similar o/p

Comment: @rookie: FYI, `[XY]` matches either `X` or `Y`. `[X|Y]` matches `X`, `|` or `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it directly with `KEYS` nor with `SCAN`, as the pattern matching that they offer does not support that.

You can, however, use a Lua script to do that:

```
local dict = {}

while (#ARGV > 0) do
    local pattern = table.remove(ARGV,1)
    local cursor = 0
    repeat
        local r = redis.call('SCAN',cursor,'MATCH',pattern)
        cursor = tonumber(r[1])
        while (#r[2] > 0) do
            dict[table.remove(r[2],1)] = true
        end
    until cursor == 0
end

local reply = {}
for k,v in pairs(dict) do
    reply[#reply+1] = k
    dict[k] = nil
end

return reply
```

Sample output:

```
$ redis-cli KEYS "*"
1) "bazfoo"
2) "bar2"
3) "foo1"
4) "qazbar"
$ redis-cli --eval scanor.lua , "foo*" "bar*"
1) "bar2"
2) "foo1"
```

Comment: No, this only does OR on Redis' pattern matching.