# Redis-cli keys "And" & "Or" commands

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm doing some validations on Redis using `redis-cli` with the following command

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern XXX:YYY:* | sort

XXX:YYY:126
XXX:YYY:13
XXX:YYY:1369
XXX:YYY:139
XXX:YYY:15
XXX:YYY:16
XXX:YYY:1657
XXX:YYY:17
XXX:YYY:2341
XXX:YYY:2349
XXX:YYY:2353
XXX:YYY:2725
XXX:YYY:2825
XXX:YYY:2837
XXX:YYY:2894
XXX:YYY:2925
XXX:YYY:2933
XXX:YYY:3699
XXX:YYY:4219
XXX:YYY:4227
XXX:YYY:4247
XXX:YYY:4451
XXX:YYY:4475
XXX:YYY:4555
```

However, I need to take specific keys for example

```
XXX:YYY:3699
XXX:YYY:4475
XXX:YYY:1657
```

Is it there a way to still use the initial pattern and do something like

> XXX:YYY:* AND (*3899 OR *4475 OR 1657)

thanks

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863037/how-to-apply-or-condition-in-redis-keys-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use grep for it, there are several patterns [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/)

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern XXX:YYY:* | sort | grep -e '3699\|4475\|1657'
```

this will print

```
XXX:YYY:1657
XXX:YYY:3699
XXX:YYY:4475
```